# How can one compile Coq code reliably using `coqc` command?

Tags: coq, coqide

I was going the the software foundations course and for some reason I could NOT get the `coqc` command to compile my libraries.

I did:

```
coqc Maps.v
```

but get the error:

> Error: The file /Users/pinocchio/coq/software_foundations_vol1/Maps.vo
>   contains library maps and not library Maps

I also tried compiling with coqIDE but I get the following error:

> Error: Compiled library Maps (in file
>   /Users/pinocchio/coq/software_foundations_vol1/Maps.vo) makes
>   inconsistent assumptions over library Coq.Init.Notations

Any ideas on what can I do?

Comment: Include the code? It seems like there may be a naming issue.

Comment: @DaveNewton I am using: https://github.com/frankYaohua/software-foundations/blob/master/Maps.v

Comment: Any reason not to get it from the source https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/current/index.html ?